# Docker private registry | TLS certificate issue

Tags: ssl, docker, registry, private, x509certificate

I've tried to follow the following [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate) to setup our own private registry (v2) on an AWS Centos machine.

I've self signed a TLS certificate and placed it in /etc/docker/certs.d/MACHINE_STATIS_IP:5000/

When trying to login the registry (docker login MACHINE_IP:5000) or push a tagged repository (MACHINE_IP:5000/ubuntu:latest) i get the following error :

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://MACHINE_IP:5000/v1/users/: x509: cannot validate certificate for MACHINE_IP because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Tried to search for an answer for 2 days, however I couldn't find any.
I've set the certificate CN (common name) to MACHINE_STATIC_IP:5000

Comment: I've managed to get a different error during DOCKER PUSH which is now :
v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a self signed TLS certificate docker daemon require you to add the certificate to it's known certificates.

Use the keytool command to grab the certificate :

`keytool -printcert -sslserver ${NEXUS_DOMAIN}:${SSL_PORT} -rfc > ${NEXUS_DOMAIN}.crt`

And copy it your client's machine SSL certificates directory (in my case - ubuntu):

`sudo cp ${NEXUS_DOMAIN}.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/${NEXUS_DOMAIN}.crt && sudo update-ca-certificates`

Now reload docker daemon and you're good to go :

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: For adding a system certificate for Fedora, use the following blog post: https://www.happyassassin.net/2015/01/14/trusting-additional-cas-in-fedora-rhel-centos-dont-append-to-etcpkitlscertsca-bundle-crt-or-etcpkitlscert-pem/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following command to temporarily trust the certificate without adding it your system certificates.

```
docker --tlscert <the downloaded tls cert> pull <whatever you want to pull>
```